# Best way to connect my substrate node with android app

Tags: rust, rpc

I do have a native app written in Java/Kotlin and I would like to connect it with my substrate node.

Which is the best way to do it? Any open-source library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how up to date this library stays, but here is a Substrate library written in Java:

https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj

And here is one in Kotlin:

https://github.com/NodleCode/substrate-client-kotlin